# Why can Chrome installation not trigger windows defender etc

Tags: windows, antivirus

I have a program - my_thing.exe - I have digitally signed it.  When a client downloads it from our website it triggers windows defender.  How do programs like Chrome do it so as not to trigger windows defender or other anti-virus?

I have digitally signed the program.

Answer (score 0):

Some legit programs already have their entries in the whitelist database of windows defender so that whenever a request is made from that application it does not get triggered.